# Keynote does not save a presentation

Tags: ipad, keynote

I face a serious problem that keeps me from working. I had been making a presentation in Keynote on iPad (8th-gen) for about 4 hours and everything was ok.  Suddenly, Keynote stopped saving my presentation, and I can no longer share it and add new things. I have enough storage on iCloud and in the iPad storage. Also, I checked the Wi-Fi connection which is ok. I'm running the latest version of Keynote. iPadOS is 14.0.1

I don't know how to fix it. Help me, please.

Comment: Is it only this presentation or has Keynote stopped saving any presentation? Are the other iWork apps (Pages, Numbers) on your iPad saving properly? Have you tried restarting your iPad?

Comment: Only this. Yes, Pages saves files. I've updated my iPad to the latest version of iPadOS (14.2). Yes, I restarted my iPad twice.

Comment: Have you tried duplicating the presentation and see what happens with the duplicate? How big is the presentation file size?

Comment: Yes, I have. The duplicate has the same time and the same size - 2,8 Mb. Keynote couldn't save it as well. I can't commit any changes.

Comment: This is weird. Have you tried deleting Keynote and reinstalling it?

Comment: Yep, very strange bug. Goog idea, I will reinstall it!

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you for helping me out. I hope it won't crush again.

Comment: Happy to hear it worked. I will add my last recommendation also as an answer. If you think reinstallation has indeed solved your problem, you can accept it as "the best answer".

Comment: If you can delete and reinstall without loosing your presentation it actually got saved. Hmm.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't add anything to the last version. The last version was saved automatically, but after 16:21 it haven't been autosaved anymore. As well I couldn't save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing appears to be a basic but unlikely problem. It is possible that the Keynote app you are using is corrupted. Pls try deleting and reinstalling it.